# Trying to capture Full Screenshot in Electron App Error in The Onclick index.html script Tag

Tags: javascript, electron

This is the Error I am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fullscreenScreenshot is not defined at HTMLInputElement
```

the code causing this is in the index.html Script tag.
Here is
The Render.js code https://pastebin.com/cEp1rJsT
The Index html Code
https://pastebin.com/WVWG69RH
Where I am building this from
Where the Error is coming from https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/280/creating-screenshots-of-your-app-or-the-screen-in-electron-framework

```
 document.getElementById("trigger").addEventListener("click", function(){
            fullscreenScreenshot(function(base64data){
                // Draw image in the img tag
                document.getElementById("my-preview").setAttribute("src", base64data);
            },'image/png');
        },false);
```

Comment: Where is the `fullscreenScreenshot` function defined? I couldn't find the code in the files you linked, just the comment `//* Here the fullscreenScreenshot function *//`

Comment: I am getting this code from here https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/280/creating-screenshots-of-your-app-or-the-screen-in-electron-framework

Comment: It looks like the example they gave requires you to paste the `fullscreenScreenshot` from the first code snippet into the second HTML snippet where the `//* Here the fullscreenScreenshot function *//` comment is in order for it to work.

Comment: This was correct! My bad That was easy.